# Convert txt to string is not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string

I've node application and Inside a folder I've txt file(long...) with content like following

```
BASH=/bin/sh
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="51" [3]="1" [4]="release" )
BASH_VERSION='3.2.2(1)-release'
CF_INSTANCE_ADDR=10.2.7:501
CF_INSTANCE_INDEX=0
CF_INSTANCE_IP=10.97.27.7
CF_INSTANCE_P='[{external:500,internal:501}]'
COLUMNS=80
```

I read the txt file content with `fs.readFile` and I need to update some property there so I think to parse it to json but this is not working

my questions is:

1. Should I parse it to json? in order to modify some property value
   such like

from

```
CF_INSTANCE_ADDR=10.2.7:501
```

to

```
CF_INSTANCE_ADDR=11.3.8:702
```

Or

```
CF_INSTANCE_P='[{external:500,internal:501}]'
```

to

```
CF_INSTANCE_P='[{external:100,internal:200}]'
```

Etc...

2. There is other better way?

This is what I tried

```
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8').then(function (response) {

       var aa =  JSON.stringify(response);
       //console.log(aa);

        var bb = JSON.parse(aa);
        console.log(bb);

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: That is nothing at all like JSON syntax.

Comment: have you tried an ini parser? [Parsing ini files](https://kangolin.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/parsing-ini-files-with-node-js/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the string to an object at which point you can decide how to proceed/tidy up the data:

```
var obj = {};
str.split(/\n/g).forEach(function (el) {
  var spl = el.split('=');
  obj[spl[0]] = spl[1];
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sorz4ymt/)

So you should be left with an object called `obj`:

```
var obj = {
  "BASH": "/bin/sh",
  "BASH_ARGC": "()",
  "BASH_ARGV": "()",
  "BASH_LINENO": "([0]",
  "BASH_VERSINFO": "([0]",
  "BASH_VERSION": "'3.2.2(1)-release'",
  "CF_INSTANCE_ADDR": "10.2.7:501",
  "CF_INSTANCE_INDEX": "0",
  "CF_INSTANCE_IP": "10.97.27.7",
  "CF_INSTANCE_P": "'[{external:500,internal:501}]'",
  "COLUMNS": "80"
}
```

You can now access the values of each key using either dot or bracket notation:

```
obj.BASH_VERSION // '3.2.2(1)-release'
obj['BASH_VERSION'] // '3.2.2(1)-release'
```

Here I'll remove those single quotes from BASH_VERSION:

```
obj.BASH_VERSION = obj.BASH_VERSION.replace("'", "");
```

Comment: Thanks Andy1+ The problem is that I get it from the read file so how should I add the /n ? in addion how should I modify field value(like in my post...), Thanks!

Comment: Well, they should already be in your imported file (they're line feeds) - I just added them to my example because they didn't exist already. Give it a go and see what happens. @JhonDree. I've changed the `split` to use a regex instead, btw.

Comment: Andy Thanks, you didnt provide the second  "split to use a regex instead, btw", and the second question how you modify some field property(like I provide in the post), can you provide example please?

Comment: I had edited the question: it now says `split(/\n/g)` instead of `split('\n')`. I'll update the answer with an example.